# Do I need to be in a constant touch with the community to get the admissions?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, communication, community

I just completed my masters degree. Some of my seniors are constantly advising me to "increase" my touch with the academic community. They say that this increases the chances of getting the admissions. Per se I have no problem with maintaining some contact with the academic community, but what irritates me is the second part of this advice. I am of an opinion that I will or won't get admissions on the basis of **my work**. If somebody likes my work they will accept me as their student, otherwise they won't. Probably this is my romantic idea about the doctoral studies as a new student. Is it really necessary to constantly attend conferences, mail the professors, be in someones good books to conduct a good doctoral study?

Comment: What do you mean by "the academic community"? Conferences are good because you can learn something and make contacts, of course, but beyond that, what?

Comment: Academic community meaning professors outside my department, seniors and so on. I am not saying conferences are bad. I personally like attending conferences, but for the subject covered in them. I have not really tried to build and maintain contacts yet. Is it a bad practice? Is it really necessary to maintain contacts for doing good researches?